# Finding the area of the region between y=x^2+x-12

Tags: integration

Finding the area of the region between y=x^2+x-12 and the x-axis

For which area am I looking for?

The area below the x axis or above? and why?

Many thanks in advanced

Comment: The question reads like it was cut off, so I understand why it seems ambiguous.  It probably means the area bounded by the curve and the $x$-axis, but this is just a guess.

Comment: As stated the problem does not make any sense. If I had to guess the problem should read: "Find the area of the region between the line $y=x^2+x-12$ and the $x$-axis."

Comment: Draw a picture. You get an upward-facing parabola that meets the $x$-axis at $x=-4$ and $x=3$. So we want the area of the region below the $x$-axis, but above the parabola.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the area below the x-axis (in my graphing program, the gray region).

[image]

Consider what would happen if we instead found the area above the axis. It would have no bounds; that is, the area would be infinite.

In general, when integrating, you are looking at the region bounded by the x-axis and the curve. Of course, in some situations (such as those containing vertical asymptotes), you may run in to difficulties.